# Elasticsearch: get the max and min value form a specific object of a maps of objects

Tags: json, elasticsearch, nested, max, min

I has this mapping for the índex on elastic, i was try to get the max value of a day for a specific sensor, but my query get the value of all the sensors.

```
  "sensor": {
    "type": "nested",
    "properties": {
      "type": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "name": {
        "type": "keyword"
      },
      "number": {
        "type": "integer"
      },
      "values": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "type": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "value": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "unit": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "Lmin": {
            "type": "float"
          },
          "Lmax": {
            "type": "float"
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

An this is the map of objects,

[image]

I need only the max and the min value of the las day from the sensor number 13, i try it but ever i get the max of all sensors.

```
  {"query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "sensor",
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "sensor.values",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "sensor.values.type": "TEMPERATURE"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "agg_by_type": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "sensor.values"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "max_value": {
          "max": {
            "field": "sensor.values.value"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm new in elasticsearch, can someone help whit this please?, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to also add the nested filter in the aggregation part to only aggregate the relevant nested documents, i.e. the ones related to `TEMPERATURE`, like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "sensor",
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "sensor.values",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "sensor.values.type": "TEMPERATURE"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "agg_by_type": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "sensor.values"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "temperature_only": {
          "filter": {
            "match": {
              "sensor.values.type": "TEMPERATURE"
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "max_value": {
              "max": {
                "field": "sensor.values.value"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thask so much, that work for me, i was close :).

If you have a time, can you showme how to put a filter by type to this query? i try with another condition of match by sensor.type = 1 or 13, but the query has a error, i can´t do the query work, example, the temperature sensor can be a sensor type 1 that has a sensor type "TEMPERATURE" an a sensor of "HUMEDYTY", an the sensor type 13 that only is a sensor type "TEMPERATURE". I need the max and min value of the sensor type 1 and type "TEMPERATURE". How a can filter this data by a range of date?

Answer (score 0):

After a few days of work in another projects, i back to try make this query and finally i can do it, now i can get the data per day, hours, and by type of sensor, thanks for your help.

This is my code if somebody are trying the same.

```
  {
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match": {
                  "mac": "34:ab:95:8f:84:c0"
                }
              }
            ],
            "filter": [
              {
                "range": {
                  "timestamp": {
                    "gte": "2021-08-10",
                    "lt": "2021-08-25"
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "sensor",
            "query": {
              "bool": {
                "must": [
                  {
                    "match": {
                      "sensor.type": 1
                    }
                  }
                ],
                "should": [
                  {
                    "nested": {
                      "path": "sensor.values",
                      "query": {
                        "bool": {
                          "must": [
                            {
                              "match": {
                                "sensor.values.type": "HUMIDITY"
                              }
                            },
                            {
                              "match": {
                                "sensor.values.type": "TEMPERATURE"
                              }
                            }
                          ]
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "values_per_day": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "timestamp",
    "fixed_interval": "1d",
    "format" : "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "agg_type": {
          "nested": {
            "path": "sensor"
          },
          "aggs": {
            "type_only": {
              "filter": {
                "match": {
                  "sensor.type": 1
                }
              },
              "aggs": {
                "agg_by_type": {
                  "nested": {
                    "path": "sensor.values"
                  },
                  "aggs": {
                    "temperature_only": {
                      "filter": {
                        "match": {
                          "sensor.values.type": "TEMPERATURE"
                        }
                      },
                      "aggs": {
                        "max_value": {
                          "max": {
                            "field": "sensor.values.value"
                          }
                        },
                        "min_value": {
                          "min": {
                            "field": "sensor.values.value"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    },
                    "humedity_only": {
                      "filter": {
                        "match": {
                          "sensor.values.type": "HUMIDITY"
                        }
                      },
                      "aggs": {
                        "max_value": {
                          "max": {
                            "field": "sensor.values.value"
                          }
                        },
                        "min_value": {
                          "min": {
                            "field": "sensor.values.value"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "from": 0,
  "sort": [
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```